# Where to store custom exception classes in a Grails project?

Tags: grails

Where it is supposed to put custom exception classes in Grails? IMO, they are not domain classes and they are not utils.

Should I/can I create a new folder `exceptions` under `grails-app`?

Answer (score 17):

Put them under src/groovy (if they are groovy classes) and src/java (if they are java classes).

Comment: Note: I think this changed after Grails 2, for Grails 3 I had to put it in src/main/groovy